# What does the tick in the project window in IntelliJ mean?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a several multi-modules of maven projects imported in IntelliJ. I recently pressed some short-cut on the keyboard and one of them (the bottom one) was marked with a tick:

[image: screen shot of the project window in IntelliJ]

What does this mean? ...and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: favorite / bookmark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added it your bookmarks.
To remove it:

1. Click on the directory with the mouse (or mark it some other way).
2. Remove bookmark using a shortcut. 
   Linux/Windows shortcut is <kbd>F11</kbd>. Mac shortcut is <kbd>F3</kbd>

If you want to view your bookmarks list, in Linux/Windows shortcut is <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, in Mac shortcut is  <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is a bookmark. Use Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle Bookmark or the corresponding keyboard shortcut to remove it.